# GitHub Actions: Cannot inherit secrets using reusable workflows

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-reusable-workflows

The [Github actions documentation on reusable workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idsecretsinherit) specifies the syntax to pass secrets from caller workflow to the called workflow using the **secrets: inherit** tag. However, when I copy this I get an error saying

```
Unexpected value 'inherit'
```

[image: the error message]

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are the repositories within the same organization, or within the same enterprise?

Comment: They are within the same organization. The workflow runs fine and I can pass the secrets manually, the error only occurs using the inherit keyword.